# file upload with jersey framework in Glassfish server

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

I try to learning file uploading in jersey. I wrote simple code to make sure it is work .when I run project in Glassfish server it give me this error . How could I solve it ?

> GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
>   C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1057:
>   The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

my code is

```
 @POST
 @Path("/upload")
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
 public String uploadFile(
 @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
 @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
 return "";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this error not belongs to glassfish server. 
Restart netbeans and clean and build your project because netbeans also write self generated code corresponding to webservices.
I recommended to use eclipse j2ee IDE.